# In TACTIC,while using server.execute_cmd() method, how do we return data to the frontend?

Tags: python, tactic

I am actually working on a TACTIC project which uses AngularJS on the frontend and Python scripts on the backend. 
Here when the python script is executed using `server.execute_cmd(cls_name,args)` from the Javascript code, the python script is run, BUT isn't able to return a value back to the front-end!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return any o/p back to the calling function, you need to populate and return **self.info**

```
self.info["your_key_here"] = [your_answer]
```

In this way, the front-end or the calling command will receive the desired return value. I hope this answers helps others who have had/or will have similar query in future.